Programmatically fail TestNG test suite
I have written a TestNG listener, which generally manages mock servers.
At the end of a test suite, in the onFinish method, the mock-servers-manager verifies that all of the defined mocks, received all expected (pre-mapped) HTTP calls.
In case there were some mismatches, I need to fail the test suite.
Throwing an AssertionException / RuntimeException does not fail the test suite.
How can I programmatically achieve this goal? My listener implements the ITestSuite interface only.
Using TestNG version 7.5.

Why don't you do those checks right inside the tests themselves? That way you know what failed and where. Also, tests should be independent anyway so the counters / mock servers should too.

@Thomas multiple tests might be using the same mock server, with different mappings. Only when all tests complete the mock HTTP calls can be verified. Having said that, this solution was developed for a certain platform and now is being adjusted for legacy code tests, so there are limitations and this is the only way it could work

"Only when all tests complete the mock HTTP calls can be verified." - I'd doubt that. You'd know what calls a test should be doing so you can verify those at the end of the test. If the tests are depending on each other that's an issue already. If you are facing limitations with how the tests are set up you might need to consider updating those. Maybe you could create a final test that depends on all the others and just does the verification - not ideal but it should be a viable solution.

@Thomas With the current implementation, it is possible to validate only after all tests run. Changing that will require a pretty major change in our testing libraries which is currently out of scope (we have developed an in house microservice platform, all testing libraries were developed by us). This is a compromise for legacy code testing, not ideal but it is what it is. There is an issue with adding a test that will trigger the validation, and that is because I don't know which tests the developers will run. This should work on all environments no matter which tests are being ran.

Unless it is possible to have a test always run no matter what, and have it run last. I will check that.

Unfortunately this would not work. I need access to the ISuite context where I have my mock-servers-manager saved.

Here's how we can fail TestNG programmatically to suite your use case.

Ensure that you are using the latest version of TestNG (7.10.2 as of today)
Create a TestNG listener, that implements org.testng.IAnnotationTransformer (so that we can alter the annotation attributes at runtime), org.testng.IAlterSuiteListener (so that we can alter a suite at runtime by adding a new test programmatically) and org.testng.IInvokedMethodListener (this is optional and I am using this just to demonstrate that the solution works)
Now create a special test case, which will do whatever checks you want to do, and also annotate that special test case, with a custom annotation, so that we know that whenever we encounter a method with our special annotation, we need to be fudging group dependencies)
In your transform() method, you just add a default upstream group to all tests and optionally add a depends on groups attribute when you encounter your special test case.
Within you alter() implementation, you wire in the special test case programmatically and also adjust the groups to be executed.

Here's a full-fledged sample code that should elaborate what I am talking about:
The listener
import org.testng.*;
import org.testng.annotations.ITestAnnotation;
import org.testng.xml.XmlClass;
import org.testng.xml.XmlSuite;
import org.testng.xml.XmlTest;

import java.lang.reflect.Constructor;
import java.lang.reflect.Method;
import java.time.Instant;
import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.time.ZoneId;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;
import java.util.stream.Stream;

public class MyMandatoryListener implements IAnnotationTransformer, IAlterSuiteListener, IInvokedMethodListener {

    @Override
    public void transform(ITestAnnotation annotation, Class testClass, Constructor testConstructor, Method testMethod) {
        if (annotation == null) return;
        String[] existingGroups = annotation.getGroups();
        if (testMethod == null) return;
        String groupNameToAdd = "upstream";
        if (testMethod.getDeclaredAnnotation(ExecuteAtLast.class) != null) {
            //We found our special test case. So let's add a group dependency
            annotation.setDependsOnGroups(appendGroup(annotation.getGroups(), "upstream"));
            groupNameToAdd = "downstream";
        }
        annotation.setGroups(appendGroup(existingGroups, groupNameToAdd));
    }

    @Override
    public void alter(List<XmlSuite> suites) {
        for (XmlSuite suite : suites) {
            for (XmlTest test : suite.getTests()) {
                List<String> existing = new ArrayList<>(test.getIncludedGroups());
                existing.addAll(List.of("upstream", "downstream"));
                test.setIncludedGroups(existing);
                List<XmlClass> classes = new ArrayList<>(test.getClasses());
                classes.add(new XmlClass(MySpecialTestCase.class));
                test.setXmlClasses(classes);
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void beforeInvocation(IInvokedMethod method, ITestResult testResult) {
        print("Started", testResult);
    }

    @Override
    public void afterInvocation(IInvokedMethod method, ITestResult testResult) {
        print("Finished", testResult);
    }

    private static void print(String prefix, ITestResult testResult) {
        String msg = prefix + " execution of " + testResult.getMethod().getMethodName() +
                " at " + prettyDate(testResult) + " on Thread [" + Thread.currentThread().getId() + "]";
        System.err.println(msg);
    }

    private static String prettyDate(ITestResult testResult) {
        DateTimeFormatter dtf = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("HH:mm:ss");
        Instant instant = Instant.ofEpochMilli(testResult.getStartMillis());
        LocalDateTime now = instant.atZone(ZoneId.of("Asia/Kolkata")).toLocalDateTime();
        return dtf.format(now);
    }

    private static String[] appendGroup(String[] existingGroups, String newGroup) {
        List<String> list = Stream.of(existingGroups).collect(Collectors.toList());
        list.add(newGroup);
        return list.toArray(new String[0]);
    }
}

The marker annotation
import java.lang.annotation.Retention;
import java.lang.annotation.Target;

import static java.lang.annotation.ElementType.METHOD;
import static java.lang.annotation.ElementType.TYPE;

@Retention(java.lang.annotation.RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target({METHOD, TYPE})
public @interface ExecuteAtLast {
}

The special testcase
import org.testng.Assert;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

public class MySpecialTestCase {

    @Test
    @ExecuteAtLast
    public void checkingTest() {
        //Replace this with the actual checks that are to be done.
        //Here we are only simulating for illustrative purposes
        boolean shouldFail = Boolean.parseBoolean(System.getProperty("fail", "true"));
        if (shouldFail) {
            //Simulating as if the required validation failed and so failing the test
            //which will cause the overall execution to fail as well
            Assert.fail("Simulating a failure");
        }
    }
}

Now you can wire in this listener using one of the ways as described in the documentation (My personal recommendation is that you use the service loader approach, so that no one needs to alter any of the existing suites etc and it just runs always)
